# Question mark in regular expressions in Javascript (weird behaviour)

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<html><body><script>
var matches = /(\w+)(\s*(\w+))?/.exec("aaa");
alert(matches.length);
alert(typeof(matches[3]));
</script></body><html>
```

I'm really new to regular expressions, so this may be a very easy question.

The regular expression above `/(\w+)(\s*(\w+))?/` matches patterns like "aaa", "123", "my_var" or "aaa bbb", "123 456", "my_var my_value".

For an expression like "aaa bbb", matches = `["aaa bbb", "aaa", " bbb", "bbb"]`, but for an expression like "aaa", matches = `["aaa", "aaa", ???, ???]`

The first thing that surprised me is that matches.length = 4. I was expecting it to be 2, but I don't see any document explaining what it should be. How does it work?

And the second thing that surprised me is that the 2 "extra" matches that I got are working different in the 2 browsers I've tested this into:

- In Firefox 3.6.3, matches[2] and matches[3] are undefined.
- In Internet Explorer 6, matches[2] and matches[3] are an empty string.

Basically, how should I check if I've got a "short" (like "aaa") or a "long" (like "aaa bbb") expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard ([ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)) is pretty clear.  The length should be 4, and IE is wrong (shocking, I know).

From §15.10.2.1, "*NcapturingParens* is the total number of left capturing parentheses."    You have 3.

"A *State* is an ordered pair (*endIndex*, *captures*) where *endIndex* is an integer and *captures* is an internal array of *NcapturingParens* values. [...] The nth element of *captures* is either a String that represents the value obtained by the nth set of capturing parentheses or **undefined** if the nth set of capturing parentheses hasn’t been reached yet."

§15.10.6.2, which describes exec, says:

> 9 . d. i. Let *r* be the *State* result of the call to [[Match]]. [...]
>
> 12 . Let *n* be the length of *r*'s *captures* array. (This is the same value as 15.10.2.1's *NCapturingParens*.)
>
> 13 . Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array() [...]
>
> 17 . Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *A* with arguments "length", Property Descriptor {[[Value]]: I + 1}, and true. [...]
>
> 20 . For each integer *i* such that *I > 0* and *I ≤ n*
>
> a. Let *captureI* be *ith* element of *r*'s *captures* array.
>
> b. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *A* with arguments ToString(*i*), Property Descriptor {[[Value]]: *captureI*, [[Writable]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true}, and true.
>
> 21 . Return *A*.

So the length should definitely be 4 (3 + 1), and captures that don't get reached (like `(\s*(\w+))` in your pattern) remain undefined.  Luckily, *undefined* and *""*  (empty string) are both falsy.  This means that they are false when treated as a boolean.  So you can work around IE's bug by doing `if(matches[2])`

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to see :)

Answer (score 3):

The `matches` array contains two kinds of matches, the whole matched string, and your embraced patterns. So in this case it has four elements, the total matched string, `"aaa"`, the first sub result, `"aaa"` again, and both `(\s*(\w+))` and `(\w+)` have empty matches.

The difference between firefox and IE is trivial.

The answer to how you should check the match results is simple, just check the value of `matches[1]` and `matches[3]`, see if they're undefined or empty. If your strings to parse are all in pattern of `\w+\s*\w+`, just `String.split()` them will be fine. The result array will be short if your string is short and will be long if your string is `"aaaa bbbb"`. Be careful with cases like `"aaa "` though.

Comment: About the 1st question, I was expecting it to have 2 matches instead of 4. But having it return a match for every parenthesis kind of makes sense.

The 2nd question is the real doubt. Since I have seen 2 different behaviors, I don't know what is it supposed to be, nor I have seen it documented. if (matches[2]) seems to work in both, but I'd like to see some documentation for this.  


I can't use String.split(), since the real regular expression is much longer and complex than that one.

Comment: @GameZelda "", 0 and undefined are all false values in JavaScript. If you are afraid of this behavior, check both conditions instead. e.g. `if (type of matches[2] === "undefined" || matches[2] === "")`

Answer (score 2):

Try it with these two regexes:

```
var m1 = /(\w+)(\s*)/.exec("aaa");   // ["aaa", "aaa", ""]
var m2 = /(\w+)(\s+)?/.exec("aaa");  // ["aaa", "aaa", undef]
```

In the first case, group #2 doesn't consume any characters, but the `*` means a zero-length match is okay; that group is said to have *matched nothing*--i.e., an empty string.  In the second case, `(\s+)` fails, but the overall match succeeds because the group itself was optional.  The `undef` result indicates that the group did not *participate in the match*.

That's how it's supposed to work: an empty string means the group participated in the match but didn't consume any characters; `undef` means it didn't participate in the match.  By returning an empty string for non-participating groups, Internet Explorer erases the distinction between a group that matches nothing and a group that doesn't match.

The situation is a lot worse than that, though, and IE is not the only bad guy; see [this blog post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/npcg-javascript) for the gory details.

But there's one thing that all browsers agree on: the number of elements in the `match` array is controlled by the number of capturing groups in the regex, whether they participate in the match or not.